# Can't upload file via curl

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

Trying to build image autoupload php tool with curl. With other uploads like text, had no problems. But when it comes to image uploading part - I am stuck. Looked through other similar problems here at SO, but couldn't find anything that would help.

With Firefox developer tool I have found that headers sent are:

```
Host: www.xxxxxx.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.xxxxxx.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------54682012365
Content-Length: 13645
Origin: https://www.xxxxxx.com
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxxxx;
TE: Trailers
```

And body request:

```
-----------------------------54682012365
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

--->THERE GOES SOMETHING I BELIEVE TO BE IMAGETOTEXT(random symbols with few readable parts)<---
-----------------------------54682012365
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ImId"

0
-----------------------------54682012365--
```

Tried to reproduce request with CURL

Sending headers as they are above.
Body request:

```
$img = file_get_contents('test.jpg');
$body_message = 
'---------------------------54682012365
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

'.$img.'
---------------------------54682012365
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ImId"

0
---------------------------54682012365--';
```

Curl options:

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_HEADER => 1, 
CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true, 
CURLOPT_POST => 1, 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body_message
```

But always get custom JSON error `'No images selected'`;

Tried various modifications with `$body_message`, tried a little bit with Curlfile, but still no success.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a silly mistake, but it took some time to realise.
If anyone comes with mistake like mine:
boundary in header and body request are different length

```
---------------------------54682012365
-----------------------------54682012365
```

And in my `$body_message` boundary was 2 dashes short

Comment: You should strongly consider something like Guzzle to do the manual work for you.